# Non-parametric confidence interval for a small sample

Tags: nonparametric, binomial-distribution, small-sample

I have a question about measuring a confidence interval for a binomial success rate using from a "small" universe. I should say that I don't think that the underlying distribution is binomial for reasons I will explain below.

We rate success and failure of projects. Projects can either succeed or failure. Every year we review between 8 and 20 projects. We review 100% of the projects that are completed.   We want to be able compare the success rate (for example 70% of projects were successful in year X) year to year and identify significant differences.

I do not believe that the projects are independent-- if we carry out too many projects, it will lower the quality of each project. Likewise, I do not think that there is an underlying mean that drives the process; conditions vary from year to year.

Since I can't use a binomial estimate, is there some sort of non-parametric method to identify the confidence interval? Is the sample too small? If we had a bigger sample (say 150), would it work better? Or perhaps with even with my earlier caveats, I should assume that the distribution is binomial?

It also occurs to me that perhaps we could do a simple probit or logit on each observation (project) and use that to identify systematic differences from year to year.

This question has been driving me crazy for the last two weeks. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many years of data have you got?

Comment: I'm not sure you have a problem here. The kind of dependency you describe might not be in the probabilistic sense. The distinction is this: you seem to be saying that the (underlying but unknowable) success rate $p_t$ in year $t$ may vary with the number of projects that year. Nevertheless, the *outcomes* of the projects can still be statistically independent. This suggests considering a generalized linear model with a binomial distribution of outcomes, rather than the rather draconian resort to wholly nonparametric methods.

Comment: Thank you! Would you recommend using a logit or probit on each observation (project) and then use the results to understand he underlying process and how it changes over time?

Comment: I have about 40 years of data. Depending on the type of project, we look have, we might have from 100 to 8,000 observations. We have the complete universe; no data are missing.